# How can I briefly display a graphic on the screen without a dialog in AppleScript?

Tags: graphics, icons, applescript, dock

I have 2 applescripts (saved as apps) that make webhook calls in a loop to control the volume of my stereo.  Each script displays a dialog that asks for a number of ticks to tick the volume up or down, and it loops to make the webhook call each time.

Background: I wrote a program called pi_bose that runs on my raspberry pi to send commands to my Bose Series 12 stereo.  It sends codes on the 28Mhz band using a wire as an antenna plugged into one of the GPIO ports.  Node red receives the webhook calls and runs that script.  But there are various things that can make it fail.  The antenna can be loose because the pi has been bumped.  Node red isn't running.  The program has a small memory leak that causes a problem after having been used for about 6 months.  And sometimes there's background interference that makes not every transmission work (I could probably use a longer antenna to address that I guess).  But sometimes, whatever is playing on the stereo is just so soft that it's hard to detect the subtle change to the volume.  And sometimes, it seems that either the webhook call happens slowly and the volume *is* changing - it just happens over the course of 20-30 seconds.  So...

I know I could do the loop on the pi itself instead of repeating the webhook call, but I would like to see progress on the mac itself.

I'd like some sort of cue that gives me some feedback to let me know each time the webhook call happens.  Like, a red dot on the AppleScript app icon or something in the corner of the screen that appears for a fraction of a second each time the webhook call is made.

Alternatively, I could make the script make some sort of sound, but I would rather not disrupt audibly whatever is playing at the time.

Does anyone know how to do that?  Is it even possible to display an icon without a dialog window in applescript?

Comment: Regular AppleScript can’t do it, but the Cocoa frameworks can be used via AppleScriptObjC to do stuff like that.

Comment: @red_menace - Do you know if there's a way to commendeer an app badge for this purpose? If not via applescript, perhaps via a shell script?

Comment: Yes, AppleScriptObjC can be used for the docktile.

Comment: I'd rethink the webhook calls being fired off on a loop. Since your scripts are encapsulated as apps, making a _Stay Open_ app offers the much better option of idling rather than looping.  Alternatively, triggering the scripts to execute by way of a shortcut or Siri command is another way.  Machines are people too, and don't deserve the hamster wheel treatment.

Comment: Showing your code for the critical parts of your app might help. You might be able to make a menu/status bar app that changes its icon colour from green to red.